# Enterprise Architect edit Class Name before "::"

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I used EA to import some source code. However, the name contains `name::className`. How can I get rid of `name`? If I highlight `name::className` it only displays `className` for editing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its an option in EA that you can turn on or off in order to show the namespace.
Check Tool|Options|Diagram and check the option "Disable fully scoped object name"
[image: disable fully scoped object names]

Comment: Is there a way to show namespace but without '::'?

Comment: @Muka not unless you use shapescripts.

Comment: Hmm, it can be a little complicated. I'm looking for an easy solution to represent endpoints.

`/base/path1/path2/{code}`

I figured I could use elements (path) one inside the other.

`> /base
>> /path1
>>> /path2
>>>> /{code}`

And when linking to a diagram, with 'fully scoped object name' enabled it would show the url. But it displays with '::'

`/base::/path1::/path2::/{code}`

Comment: I am following your sugestion.  In the [Shape Script Examples](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.0/modeling/example_scripts.html) we have one that shows 'Qualified Name' that returns the name with '::'. Is there any function to replace '::' with '\'?

Comment: @Muka I don't think so, unless you call an add-in from your shape script. But it might be worth a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable 'namespace' at individual diagram level as well. Go to 'diagram' properties-->diagram tab-->uncheck 'show namespace' option.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is dirty but if the imported items need significant massaging, I will rename the .EAP to .MDB and then use sql updates in MS-ACCESS. Once I am done, I rename back to EAP.

Comment: I think in this case the data itself is OK, it's just the way it is visualized in EA that bothers barq